# What does element size represents?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I saw the annotation `@Size` as a restriction in a Spring controller. 
I was looking for an explanation to what exactly is the size and I found this:

> The size of the field or property is evaluated and must match the specified boundaries. If the field or property is a String, the size of the string is evaluated. If the field or property is a Collection, the size of the Collection is evaluated. If the field or property is a Map, the size of the Map is evaluated. If the field or property is an array, the size of the array is evaluated. Use one of the optional max or min elements to specify the boundaries.

However it wasn't clear to me how do you calculate String's size. is it the number of chars in it? is it the number of bytes? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say where you found that explanation, but `javax.validation.constraints.Size` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) says

```
The annotated element size must be between the specified boundaries (included).
Supported types are:

  CharSequence (length of character sequence is evaluated)
  Collection (collection size is evaluated)
  Map (map size is evaluated)
  Array (array length is evaluated)

  null elements are considered valid.
```

Note that `String` is a `CharSequence`

Comment: That's will do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*It is the number of characters in the string.*

The `@Size`[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) says:

```
The annotated element size must be between the specified boundaries (included).
Supported types are:

CharSequence (length of character sequence is evaluated)
Collection (collection size is evaluated)
Map (map size is evaluated)
Array (array length is evaluated)

null elements are considered valid.
```

A `String` is a `CharSequence` and if we look at the comment of the `length()` method in this interface we see:

> The length is the number of 16-bit chars in the sequence.

see http://beanvalidation.org/ for more details on `@Size` and other validators.